# Trying to store Bukkit ItemStack field to a file but ItemStack is not Serrializable

Tags: java, serialization, minecraft, bukkit

ItemStack is not serializable and I'm trying to save an object called Objective with an ItemStack field to a file but since ItemStack is not serializable this does not work. I tried extending ItemStack and implementing Serializable and changing the field to my new serializable sub class but this also did not work. Here are the relevant parts of my original code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

public class Objective implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2018456670240873538L;

private static ArrayList<Requirement> requirements = new ArrayList<>();

private String name;
private Requirement requirement;
private ItemStack reward;

private int tillComplete;

private boolean complete;

public Objective(String name, int requirementIndex, int tillComplete, ItemStack reward) {

    if(requirements.isEmpty()) {
        requirements.add(Requirement.kill_Skeletons);
        requirements.add(Requirement.kill_Spiders);
        requirements.add(Requirement.kill_Zombies);
    }


    this.name = name;
    this.requirement = requirements.get(requirementIndex);
    this.tillComplete = tillComplete;
    this.reward = reward;
    complete = false;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Object getRequirement() {
    return requirement;
}

public static ArrayList<Requirement> getRequirements() {
    return requirements;
}

public static void setRequirements(ArrayList<Requirement> requirements) {
    Objective.requirements = requirements;
}

public int getTillComplete() {
    return tillComplete;
}

public void setTillComplete(int tillComplete) {
    this.tillComplete = tillComplete;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setRequirement(Requirement requirement) {
    this.requirement = requirement;
}

public void setReward(ItemStackSerializable reward) {
    this.reward = reward;
}

public void setComplete(boolean complete) {
    this.complete = complete;
}

public ItemStack getReward() {
    return reward;
}

public boolean isComplete() {
    return complete;
}
```

}

Elsewhere in my code this line of code:

```
ItemStack reward = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD);
                        Objective objective = new Objective(args[1] ,Integer.parseInt(args[2]), Integer.parseInt(args[3]), reward);
```

is giving me this error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack
```

How can I serialize this object? I need to store it but Java wont let me. Thanks for your help. If you need anymore code snippets or other information please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely an XY problem. `ItemStack` is not serializable, as it represents an actual stack of items at runtime. This would not make sense to store in a file. It might be worth looking at the [`ConfigurationSerializable`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/configuration/serialization/ConfigurationSerializable.html) interface, which is implemented by `ItemStack`, but I don't think you need that here.

In your example, the `ItemStack` that you are trying to serialize doesn't have any metadata. It is a single diamond sword. If all your rewards are just a single item, all you need to save is the `Material` and you can create a new `ItemStack` from that `Material` every time you want to give a player a reward. Since `Material` is an `enum`, it is serializable by default.

You could also serialize an `int` for stack size if some of your rewards require a stack of multiple items. If you need any metadata, serialize the data needed to construct that at runtime. For example, to give an item lore, you would store a `List<String>` (with a serializable implementation of `List`).

Comment: Note that ItemStacks may also contain NBT data, but fortunately NBT data is also serializable.